# My answer is 36225. Please verify if it is correct

Tags: combinatorics

A computer program prints out all integers from 0 to ten thousand in base 6 using the numerals 0,1,2,3,4 and 5. How many numerals it would have printed ?

Comment: So you have to find number of digits used?

Comment: $1(6) + 2(36-6) + 3(216-36) + 4(1296-216) + 5(7776-1296) + 6(10001-7776)=50676$?

Comment: When you say "ten thousand", what do you mean?  Do you mean $10000_{10}$ or $10000_6$?

Comment: @Saketh Malyala Thank u so much.

Comment: Just to be clear: "ten thousand" in base 6 is exactly the same as in base 10, which can be written as ${10000}_{10}$ or ${114144}_{6}$. On the other hand ${10000}_{6}$ is not "ten thousand".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers from $0$ to $5$ have $1$ digit in base $6$.

The numbers from $6$ to $35$ have $2$ digits in base $6$.

The numbers from $36$ to $215$ have $3$ digits in base $6$.

The numbers from $216$ to $1295$ have $4$ digits in base $6$.

The numbers from $1296$ to $7775$ have $5$ digits in base $6$.

The numbers from $7776$ to $10000$ have $6$ digits in base $6$.

Adding the ranges up, you get

$1(6) + 2(36-6) + 3(216-36) + 4(1296-216) + 5(7776-1296) + 6(10001-7776)=50676.$